# tyrus standalone client how can I bind to one specific nic card on my host

Tags: websocket, bind, tyrus

Only one of the host's interfaces has a network route specified and without specifying a bind address my connection success with the server has been random.

How can I configure the Tyrus Standalone client with the interface to bind to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that v1.19 introduced the client property "SOCKET_BINDING" that is used to set the Property name for defining local binding address for all socket created by the client.